# Easy Putnam Question

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-writing, contest-math

I am in high school and have been trying to solve this problem for a few days. There should be no advanced calculus. I believe that there are no functions that work, but I can’t figure out how to prove that using math for every type of function. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the qustion:

Find all continuous positive functions, $0\le x \le 1$ That satisfy:
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=1$$
$$\int_0^1f(x)xdx=\alpha$$
$$\int_0^1f(x)x^2dx=\alpha^2$$
where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary real constant

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would first restrict the problem for $f$ being a polynomial.

Comment: Welcome. Strange to title “easy” when you in fact find it hard. You should provide a description of what the problem is in the title itself

Comment: The quantifications are a bit unclear here. It is "*for each $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, find the functions...*" or is it "*find the functions... ...such that... ...for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$*"? I.e. do the functions depend on $\alpha$?

Comment: Some simple analysis gives $0\lt\alpha\lt1$

Comment: hint: since $f$ is positive and normalized, it is a probability distribution. Use the problem information to calculate the variance of $f$

Comment: Equivalent to the intuition about probability, $\int_0^1f(x)(x-\alpha)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=0$ and the positive continuous criterion yields $f(x)(x-\alpha)^2\equiv0,f\equiv0$ which contradicts the hypotheses

Comment: It's [here](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol642.html) and I remember it has been posted on this site as well but couldn't find the duplicate.

Comment: I don't suppose that this is the intended answer, but if we allow the Dirac delta function and $0<\alpha<1$ then $f(x)=\delta (x-\alpha)$ does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the integrals $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$ for convenience.

$$I_1 = \int_0^1 f(x) \text{dx} = 1$$

$$I_2 = \int_0^1 xf(x) \text{dx} = \alpha$$

$$I_3 = \int_0^1 x^2f(x) \text{dx} = \alpha^2$$

Then $\alpha^2I_1 - 2\alpha I_2 + I_3 = \alpha^2 - 2\alpha^2 + \alpha^2 = 0$.

But also, $\alpha^2 I_1 - 2\alpha I_2 + I_3 = \int_0^1 \alpha^2f(x) - 2axf(x) + x^2f(x) \text{dx} = \int^1_0(\alpha-x)^2f(x)\text{dx}$.

Therefore $\int_0^1 (\alpha-x)^2 f(x) \text{dx} = 0$, which forces $f(x) = 0$. Which means that $I_1 \neq 1$ so no function $f$ exists.